# What is the standard literature on Inverse Probability Weighting Estimators?

Tags: treatment-effect

I understand that Imbens has several papers on IPW, but was wondering if there was a default text one would recommend to understand IPW. For example, where does the estimator:

$$
\tau = \frac{1}{N^T}\sum_{i=1}^N \frac{W_iY_i}{e_i(X_i)} - \frac{1}{N^C}\sum_{i=1}^N \frac{(1-W_i)Y_i}{1-e_i(X_i)}
$$

come from?

Specifically, it appears that normally an estimator will $\frac{1}{N}$ on the outside of both sums instead of what I have above as $\frac{1}{N^T}$ and $\frac{1}{N^C}$. If I replaced $\frac{1}{N^T}$ and $\frac{1}{N^C}$ with $\frac{1}{N}$, is it estimating something else?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Intuitive explanation for inverse probability of treatment weights (IPTWs) in propensity score weighting?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/273367/intuitive-explanation-for-inverse-probability-of-treatment-weights-iptws-in-pr)

Comment: Is this a dupe?  This question is looking for a reference, that one was looking for an explanation.  I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a derivation of the average treatment effect formula on [p. 240-241](https://books.google.com/books?id=TT8sBQAAQBAJ&lpg=PT361&dq=propensity%20score%20analysis%20guo%20%22Consider%20the%20term%22&pg=PT361#v=onepage&q&f=false) of Guo and Fraser's *Propensity Score Analysis*, which has a chapter devoted to IPW. This is a useful book aimed at the applied researcher, but it also contains references to the primary literature.

I don't know of any other textbook that covers this material very well.

Comment: It appears that in pg. 240 they have $\frac{1}{N}$ on the outside of both sums instead of what I have above as $\frac{1}{N^T}$ and $\frac{1}{N^C}$. Are these the same?

Comment: @user321627 They are not. All my sources have $\frac{1}{N}$. Typically, the other two pop up in formulas for ATT. It's possible that your source has non-standard notation, and there is some normalization/stabilization that makes the formulas the same, but hard to know without a citation.

Answer (score 3):

Imbens and Rubin give it on page 274 of [Causal Infernece](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521885884) without any real attribution. It looks like the estimator is there in [Hirano, Imbens and Ridder (2003)](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/1468-0262.00442/abstract). Whether it could be traced any earlier is left as an exercise to the interested reader.

Comment: I think the usual proto-reference is the Horvitz and Thompson 1952 JASA paper, where the application is re-weighting to deal with sample attrition rather treatment-control imbalance.

Comment: I need to rethink my life, @DimitriyV.Masterov. Or at least read the freaking paper.